# PHP gettext returns input as result in Homestead

Tags: php, gettext, homestead, po

In a project of our company we use gettext to translate text. This has been working for several years, but now I am trying to run the project in Homestead, everything works fine except gettext. When use for example `gettext('input_string')` it returns `input_string`. On our server and in MAMP everything is working fine. What could be the problem? I am running the project on Apache and PHP 7.0 (same as the server and MAMP)

The domain for locales is binded like this:

```
bindtextdomain('projectname', APPLICATION_PATH. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'locale');
textdomain('projectname');
bind_textdomain_codeset('projectname', 'UTF-8');
```

The path in the bindtextdomain is correct. The file structure is:

```
 - locale
   - en_US
     - LC_MESSAGES
       - projectname.mo
       - projectname.po
   - fr_FR
     - LC_MESSAGES
       - projectname.mo
       - projectname.po
   - nl_NL
     - LC_MESSAGES
       - projectname.mo
       - projectname.po
   - pt_PT
     - LC_MESSAGES
       - projectname.mo
       - projectname.po
```

Comment: Seems `gettext()` can't find your language files, since it's echoing the input string.

Comment: @Anuga I added the binding and the structue of the language files to the original question

Comment: missing subfolder in language folders = `LC_MESSAGES`.

Comment: Whoops sorry, it's there. Just forgot to mention. Updated my question.

Comment: And you've set, `$lang = "en_US";` , `putenv("LC_ALL={$lang}");` , `setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);` ?

Comment: yes `setlocale(LC_ALL, DEFAULT_LOCALE); putenv('LC_ALL=' . DEFAULT_LOCALE);`

Comment: Okey, one last thing :) Verify that it's not looking for `projectname.UTF-8.mo` and `projectname.UTF-8.po`.

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186055/discussion-between-anuga-and-bart-bergmans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale wasn't installed on Homestead. Fixed it by using `sudo locale-gen nl_NL`